# extracting the indices from pandas series that are values in the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary where keys are of string type and values are pandas series that have the 'index value' structure. I want to extract pandas series indices and make them keys in another dictionary with values per each index. Are there any ways I can transform one dictionary into another? Thanks.

This is the example of the dictionary I am working with:

```
value = pd.Series([5,5,5])
key = ['one', 'two', 'three']
dic = {}

for i in key:
        dic[i] = value      
print(dic)
```

Comment: To better understand your issue, provide input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_dic).T #transpose
new_dic = df.to_dict()
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to get rid of the keys. Anyway - thanks! Now I know how to be creative with dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies if I was not clear enough. I will update the post.

I figured out another way to do so:

```
rec = pd.Series([])

for item in key:
    rec=rec.append(dic[item])
```